# Have an issue in inserting the data into teradata from a hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, teradata

I have an issue in inserting the data into teradata from a hive table.

```
Error: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException : unknown error         at
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)         at 
java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)         at
java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)         at
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)         at 
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)         at 
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)         at
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$Lookup.doLookup(TDNetworkIOIF.java:223)         at
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$Lookup.getAddresses(TDNetworkIOIF.java:261)         at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.connectToHost(TDNetworkIOIF.java:381)         at 
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.createSocketConnection(TDNetworkIOIF.java:156)
```

When I am trying to insert the data into the Teradata table which is read from a data frame is throwing an error

Comment: Can you add more information about your problem please

Comment: When I am trying to insert the data into the Teradata table which is read from a data frame is throwing an error